# Is there no way to create a pull request on a different organization's repo?

Tags: rest, github

Using the [GitHub API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/pulls/pulls?apiVersion=2022-11-28#create-a-pull-request) v3, I attempted to create a pull request on Microsoft's repository. (The base repo is not mine and I don't have write permissions to the base repo.) For the token, I enabled write permissions on my own repo which is a fork of Microsoft's and I enabled the pull request permission.

```
POST https://api.github.com/repos/microsoft/winget-pkgs/pulls
Accept: application/vnd.github+json
Authorization: Bearer <token>
X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28

{
  "title":"Amazing new feature",
  "body":"Please pull these awesome changes in!",
  "head":"MakotoE:master",
  "base":"master",
  "draft":true
}
```

But it just responds

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden

{
  "message": "Resource not accessible by personal access token",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/pulls/pulls#create-a-pull-request"
}
```

If I change the request URL to my own repo, then I can create pull requests. I suspect that I need write permissions for the repo shown in the URL.

It's puzzling why I'm forbidden from creating a pull request when I can easily do it in the web UI.

[image]

Is it possible to create a pull request on someone else's repo with the API? If so, how?